# Zend Framework 3 Form Fieldset

Tags: zend-framework3

Hy,
I'm really new to Zend-Framework 3 and I'm practicing OOP, I can't find a simple explanation/tutorial on making a Zend Form with a fieldset and legend. Basically I'm trying to create this in HTML:

```
<form name="my_name">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>My legend value</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name_1" value="value_1">Value 1</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name_2" value="value_2">Value_2</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name_3" value="value_3">Value_3</input>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" value="Get values" id="btn"/>
</form>
```

I checked the official documentation about Zend Forms and Collections and Fieldsets, but it's really confusing me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I am sorry as it is going to be a bit long one. But this would describe the form in action. So be patient please!

Assuming you are known to ZF3 default `Application` module. Some folders are created in the `Application` module for separation of each element. You need to create them as follows.

Let's get started by creating your fieldsets first. `Zend\Form\Fieldset` component represents a reusable set of elements and is dependent on `Zend\From\Form` component. This means you need to attach this to `Zend\Form\Form`.

**module/Application/src/Form/Fieldset/YourFieldset.php**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form\Fieldset;

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class YourFieldset extends Fieldset
{

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('your-fieldset');

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'name_1',
            'type' => Element\Checkbox::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Value 1',
                'use_hidden_element' => true,
                'checked_value' => 'yes',
                'unchecked_value' => 'no',
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                 'value' => 'no',
            ],
        ]);
        // Creates others as your needs
    }
}
```

Now we would create the form using `Zend\From\Form` attaching the fieldset created from `Zend\From\Fieldset`.

**module/Application/src/Form/YourForm.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Application\Form;

use Application\Form\Fieldset\YourFieldset;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class YourForm extends Form
{

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('your-form');

        $this->add([
            // This name will be used to fetch each checkbox from 
            // the CheckboxFieldset::class in the view template.
            'name' => 'fieldsets',
            'type' => YourFieldset::class
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => [
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Get Values',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Our from is almost ready. We need to make it serviceable if we want it to be used in any action of a controller. So let's do that.

Update your module config file. If `service_manager` key does not exist then add the following snippet of code, otherwise, update only `factories` and `aliases` key as the following.

Fix **namespaces** in module config file.

**module/Application/config/module.config.php**

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        // Form service
        Form\YourForm::class => Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory::class,

        // Other services
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        // Make an alias for the form service
        'YourForm' => Form\YourForm::class,          
    ],
],
```

Now the form is ready to be used. This needs to be injected into our controller. As I am working on `Application` module, I would inject the form into the `IndexController::class`'s constructor. Then we would be using that form inside `IndexController::fieldsetAction()` method.

**module/Application/src/Controller/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Form\FormInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $YourForm;

    public function __construct(FormInterface $YourForm) 
    {
        $this->YourForm = $YourForm;
    }

    public function fieldsetAction()
    {
        $request   = $this->getRequest();
        $viewModel = new ViewModel(['form' => $this->YourForm]);

        if (! $request->isPost()) {
            return $viewModel;
        }

        $this->YourForm->setData($request->getPost());

        if (! $this->YourForm->isValid()) {
            return $viewModel;
        }

        $data = $this->YourForm->getData()['fieldsets'];

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';

        return $viewModel;
    }    
}
```

As this controller is taking argument in its constructor, we need to create a factory for this controller (a factory creates other objects).

**module/Application/src/Factory/Controller/IndexControllerFactory.php**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Factory\Controller;

use Application\Controller\IndexController;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {   
        // We get form service via service manager here
        // and then inject controller's constructor 
        $YourForm = $container->get('YourForm');
        return new IndexController($YourForm);
    }    
}
```

Once again, we need to update the module config file. We would add this time the factory under `controllers` key as follows

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => Factory\Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

At the end, echo the form in the view template as follows:

**module/Application/view/application/index/fieldset.phtml**

```
<h1>Checkbox Form</h1>

<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url());

// Here is the catch, remember this name from the CheckboxForm::class
$fieldset = $form->get('fieldsets');

$name_1 = $fieldset->get('name_1');

$name_2 = $fieldset->get('name_2');

$name_3 = $fieldset->get('name_3');

$submit = $form->get('submit');
$submit->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');

$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>

<fieldset>
    <legend>My legend value</legend>
    <?= $this->formElement($name_1) ?>
    <?= $this->formLabel($name_1) ?>

    <?= $this->formElement($name_2) ?>
    <?= $this->formLabel($name_2) ?>

    <?= $this->formElement($name_3) ?>
    <?= $this->formLabel($name_3) ?>

    <?= $this->formSubmit($submit) ?>
</fieldset>

<?php
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. This is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm. :)

Comment: This is a cool mini-tutorial.  One gotcha, though:  If you're in the habit of having the normal ServiceManager handle your forms, you can get bitten when you start to do fancier things, eg. custom elements.  

As a best practice, you're supposed to let the FormElementManager handle them.

See https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/advanced/#creating-custom-elements and search for "the second catch" and the "Handling Dependencies" section after.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the example you are looking for is in "collections" part of zend form. Its not the exact one but kinda like.

Here you are a little example. I ignored namespaces and hope so there's no typo :)

```
class myFieldset extends Fieldset {
    public function init(){
      $this
         ->add([
           'name' => 'name_1,
           'type' => 'text',
      ])
         ->add([
           'name' => 'name_2,
           'type' => 'text',
      ])
         ->add([
           'name' => 'name_3,
           'type' => 'text',
      ]);
    }
}


class MyForm extends Form {
     public function init(){
         $this->add([
             'type' => myFieldset,
              'name' => 'fieldset'
         ])->add([
             'type' => 'button',
              'name' => 'action'
         ]);
     }
}
```

And in view file;

```
<?=$this-form($form);?>
```

Comment: Oh sorry. you were looking for checkbox. this means you will render form yourself.