# Creating zend form element array with same name (ZF3)?

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Since i've to position checkboxes in design I'm not using MultiCheckbox and using Checkbox instead in zend. I've seen some [zf1 solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907687/zend-form-input-name-with-same-name) but didnt found any zf2 or zf3 solutions.

My Php Code

```
$languages = new \Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox('languages[]');
$languages->setLabel('English');
$languages->setValue('1');
```

This produce the following output

```
<?php 
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('languages[]')); 
    //It produce the following
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="languages[]" value="1" checked="checked">
```

How can I add more items with name "languages[]" without writing direct HTML code ?

Comment: Hope, this answer would help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47158149/7935051

Comment: Just render the form row multiple times:  $this->formRow($form->get('languages[]'));

Comment: @JannesBotis but its value is different for each checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **Form collection** for this:

1) In your form:

```
use Zend\Form\Element\Collection;

...

$languages = new \Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox();
$languages->setLabel('English');
$languages->setValue('1');
$languages->setName('language');

$collection = new Collection();
$collection->setName('languages');
$collection->setLabel('Language Collection');
$collection->setCount(2);
$collection->setTargetElement($languages);
$collection->populateValues(array(
        1, 0
));

$this->add($collection);
```

2) Do not forget to prepare your form in your controller action:

```
$form->prepare();
```

3) Finally, in your view, get all elements of the collection and render them separately:

```
<?php $elements = $form->get('languages')->getElements(); ?>
<?php //echo $this->formCollection($form->get('languages')); ?>
<?php echo $this->formRow($elements[0]); ?>
<?php echo $this->formRow($elements[1]); ?>
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to add next language ?

Comment: If you want to use different labels for each checkbox, add $collection->getElements()[1]->setLabel('Spanish'); in your Form.

Comment: It didn't worked, also it look like when we call "$collection->getElements()[1]" we have retrieved the element object at that position, so setLabel might not update the variable $collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (Method 2)

**Method 1:**
Give name as "language[1]" instead of "language[]". By using this I can call the elements in view seperately.

Creating form.

```
$language1 = new \Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox('language[1]');
$language2 = new \Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox('language[2]');

$form = new Form('Set');
$form->add($name)
        ->add($language1)
        ->add($language2)
        ->add($submit);
```

In view file

```
<div><?php echo $form->get('language[1]');?></div>
<div><?php echo $form->get('language[2]');?></div>
```

**Edit: Method 2**
Using fieldset

```
//Create form
$languages = [
    ['id' => 1, 'language' => 'English'],
    ['id' => 2, 'language' => 'Malayalam'],
] ;
$fieldSet = new \Zend\Form\Fieldset('languages') ;
foreach( $languages as $one ) {
    $c = new \Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox($one['id']);
    $c->setLabel($one['language']) ;            
    $fieldSet->add($c) ;
}
//Add collection of checkboxes to form
$form->add($fieldSet) ;
```

In view file

```
<?php
$language = $form->get('languages') ;
?>        
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Choose Languages</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <?php foreach($language as $one ) { ?>
        <?php echo $this->formCheckbox($one); ?> <span> <?php echo $this->formLabel( $one ) ; ?> </span>
        <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($one); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MultiChebox**

> https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.element.multicheckbox.html

It works similar to **radio** form element. Your example implementation

```
use Zend\Form\Element;

$languages = new Element\MultiCheckbox('languages');
$languages->setLabel('Used languages');
$languages->setValueOptions([
    'en_US' => 'english',
    'de_DE' => 'german',
    'pl_PL' => 'polish',
]);
$languages->setValue('en_US'); //default value; you can use array
```